# Analytics to the frontend or backend

Tags: mobile, cordova, analytics

I'm creating a mobile app with phonegap (BB/iPhone Platforms) with a backend that serves the data as json and I want to add an analytic to it. Should add it to the front end app or to the backend? What's the best approach?

Comment: Are you sharing the backend with other apps like WebApp?